# How to solve logarithm word problem given the exponential equation?

Tags: logarithms

The question is

The world population in 2000 was approximately 6.08 billion. The annual rate of increase was about 1.26%. The function that models this is $$ y = 6.08(10)^{.0052t}$$ where y represents the population in billions and  ***t***  is the time in years after 2000. Write and solve a logarithmic equation to determine what year the world population will exceed 7.5 billion.

So is the question asking me to convert the given equation into logarithmic equation than
$$ 7.05 = 6.08(10)^{.0052t} $$ ( 7.5 billion is y right?)
$$ 7.05/6.08 = 10^{.0052t} $$
$$ 1.15  = 10^{.0052t} $$
$$ log(1.15) =.0052t $$
How would i even solve after that? is the way I've done so far good? how would i proceed after this than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

How do you solve the equation $$15 = 0.0052 t?$$

Comment: divide by .0052

Comment: @MATHASKER ..There you go.

Comment: wait how did the .0052t go down from the exponent in the queston?

Comment: @MATHASKER That's how logarithms work! $\log(10^x) = x$

Comment: Oh okay but even if i go on to solve after that i still woulnd't get the right answer? did i do the steps correctly?

Comment: @MATHASKER Try replacing $7.05$ with $7.5$...

Comment: so $$log(1.233) = 0.09115768411$$ divide by .00052 would be really small to be the answer

Comment: @MATHASKER What's the question?

Comment: The question is to find when the population would be 7.5 billion..so $$.09115768411 /  .0052 = 17.5$$ I am sorry for not seeing the answer, thanks i found the answer

Comment: i have another question, its about exponents, do you mind answering?

Comment: @MATHASKER Sure. But this question is answered, meaning you should accept the answer and ask a **new** question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31163/discussion-between-math-asker-and-5xum).